# Unknown error occurred while loading my scene. Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

So I have a big problem on my Unity project.
I worked yesterday and I didn't make a backup
Today after I opened the project my laptop shutdown because I was low on battery. After that when I entered the project I got this:
Unknown error occurred while loading 'Assets/MyScene.unity'.
I don't know why my scene can't load.

[image]

Comment: You better use Git next time, I think your scene is corrupted, I saw this once.

Comment: I will definitely next time.. Hopefully I can find a solution.

Comment: Or use Time Machine if you're on a Mac

Comment: I don't have a Mac, do you know any software to recover files from yesterday?

Comment: Including editor logs can reveal what the problem is.

Open your project and wait until the error happens. Click Console -> three dots on the top right -> Open Editor Log. See if you can spot the error log near the bottom of the file.

Answer (score 3):

Not a very nice error to get when there's no backups in place... There's a workaround for this which was reported by [OrdinaryDev83](https://forum.unity.com/threads/unknown-error-occurred-while-loading-scene-name.348964/)

> Get into your scene folder and right click on the .unity file and with
> Unity opened in your project select "Edit Unity scene file", then
> you'll be in your scene but you now have to copy all the elements of
> your hierarchy (Ctrl+A) and then paste it into a new scene. Delete the
> old one (corrupted) and rename the new one with the name of the old
> one.

Comment: my scene is empty if I open the scene with "Edit Unity scene file". Any other suggestion, would be really helpful

Comment: I got no errors sorry for the late response. Last time there were some errors, this situation is weird. Do you have any other suggestion? Maybe I need to redo my scene all over again..

Comment: Yes @noob234 if the procedure mentioned above didn't work, the best is to do it all over. Make sure this time to use a version control system

Comment: @noob234 for version control I have used [Unity Teams](https://unity.com/products/unity-teams). The Project history was a really helpful section. The Basic tier if free for small teams up to 3 team members and it gives you 1GB cloud storage.